# Braintree Sandbox Testing (fake nonces)

Tags: php, sandbox, braintree

I am testing the Braintree sandbox (PHP) and even though I am using a fake-nonce, the transactions still show goes through **valid**

I have a dropin frontend and a PHP Backend

My backend code for testing looks like below:

```
$amount = '12.00';
$nonce = 'fake-processor-declined-visa-nonce';
$result = Braintree_Transaction::sale(['amount' => $amount, 
                                       'paymentMethodNonce' => $nonce, 
                                       'options' => ['submitForSettlement' => true]
                                      ]);
$debug = get_object_vars($result);
print_r($debug);
```

outcome

```
Array
(
    [success] => 1
    [transaction] => Braintree\Transaction Object
        (
            [_attributes:protected] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 9bnyb32r
                    [status] => submitted_for_settlement
                    [type] => sale
                    [currencyIsoCode] => EUR
                    [amount] => 12.00
                    [merchantAccountId] => somenamehere
                    [subMerchantAccountId] => 
                    [masterMerchantAccountId] => 
                    [orderId] => 
                    [createdAt] => DateTime Object
```

I assued the fake nouces are there for testing error outcome in the sandbox...or am I missing something

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/testing/php#test-amounts

Answer (score 8):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Invalid nonces trigger an unsuccessful [card verification response](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/credit-cards/server-side/php#verification-results), but do not cause transactions to fail. In order to simulate an unsuccessful transaction, adjust the [amount of the transaction](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/testing/php#test-amounts) instead.

Comment: are you able to provide a credit card number that we can use . this credit card would be verified successfully but at the time of applying payment would fail at the bank. this is very convenient for UI functional testing. it would be good if we could have a credit card that gave a valid nonce but it would fail when applying the payment.

Comment: for those who might have the same question as @j2emanue in the future: Braintree provides fake cards we can use to simulate transactions (they only work in the sandbox afaik). They can be found here: https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/testing/php#no-credit-card-errors

Comment: so your saying if in android i have your production sdk that i cant use these credit cars you provided in the link ? or are you saying my server has to be sandboxed ?  im looking to have a credit card that can be fake in android client. i dont have control of server. i want it to fail at bank check time.

Comment: The values at the link provided will only work against the **Braintree sandboxed env** (which can be [configured for free](https://www.braintreepayments.com/sandbox), and is totally isolated from their production env -- not your production env). I would highly recommend setting one up. I think it's risky to test payments directly against production. Not to mention, the account could look fraudulent by failing over and over against production and may trigger alerts on the gateway provider's end. BTW, I'm not affiliated with Braintree, that's Dana.

Comment: @Dana I don't know if you still work there, but this is kind of a shame that it doesn't trigger a decline down the line. Messing about with 'amount' gets trickier to manage depending upon your environment - and it would be nice to create a vaulted payment method (via a fake nonce) that would fail - to simulate a closed account / expired card etc. At least as an option. And I realize that maybe just the way your system works this is too tricky to implement - but it is very surprising that I'm allowed to vault a fake nonce (verifycard=false) that succeeds. Perhaps it shouldn't let me vault it?

Answer (score 3):

Trying to test some similar things in PHP, I found some helpful, well-named test nonces in `\Braintree\Test\Nonces` in the PHP Braintree library. I was able to use `fake-valid-visa-nonce` to do the testing I needed to create a new payment method.

Comment: thanks, their test cases provided really good examples on how to set things up!

Comment: Thank you, this was what got me back on track. MVP. For anyone here, look here: https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ruby/blob/master/lib/braintree/test/nonce.rb

Answer (score 1):

You can use the string 'fake-valid-nonce' as the nonce for testing sale transactions. You can find more fake nonce info in the braintree testing docs, https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/testing/php